# How much delay can be achieved using jiffies in kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, delay, linux-device-driver

I need to emulate MDC/MDIO bus using the bit-banging for MDC line. I need to get a clock with frequency of 1.5 Mhz, 1 Mhz will also do.
I am trying to use `udelay` and `ndelay` from `linux/delay.h`. I am working with kernel 2.6.32 and MPC8569E processor from freescale. `ndelay` is not giving me dealy in nanoseconds but microseconds, I saw it using a logic analyzer on the wires. So `ndelay(1)` and `udelay(1)` are effectively behaving the same, giving 1 microsecond delay.
Now In a bit-bang model the codes gonna be something like

```
par_io_data_set(2/*C port*/,30 /*MDIO pin*/,val /*value*/); //write data to the line MDIO line

//clock pulse for setting the data
ndelay(MDIO_DELAY); 
par_io_data_set(2/*C port*/,31 /*MDC pin*/,1 /*value*/); 
ndelay(MDIO_DELAY);                                        
par_io_data_set(2/*C port*/,31 /*MDC pin*/,0 /*value*/);
```

Where I have defined `MDIO_DELAY` as 1. So I am able to get a clock of around 0.4MHz. I want to bitbang at 1.5 Mhz, but *I can't just do so until I can't give delay in nanoseconds*.

So I was looking at chapter 7 of ldd, jiffies. Well my HZ is 250, so the kernel interrupts for time every 1/250 secs i.e. 4milli secs right? So jiffies gonna be incremented every 4ms. So I can't expect jiffies to get a counter of the order of nano-seconds, right?

How do I get this job done?

Comment: If you want to get a high precision in measuring time lapses, you could always use `get_cycles()` which returns the no. of clock cycles passed. By using this with the CPU's clock frequency, you could achieve the desired delay precisely.

Comment: can you share an example code or link for the same.

Comment: I guess `get_cycles()` is implemented for my processor, I used it in my driver code, just printed the value returned, its not zero. So I now get the clock cycles lapsed between 2 points, how to get CPU's clock frequency. Can you share a simple sample code.

Comment: try `cpufreq_quick_get(n)`

Comment: it just returns zero, additionally I saw that only the prototype is defined in `include/linux/cpufreq.h`, where would be the definition? Can I just include the file and use it.

Comment: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/cpufreq/cpufreq.c#L1541